# FirebaseQuery Observer not Removing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I add an observer in viewWillAppear and remove it in viewWillDisappear. I switch tabs than manually add something to the posts ref and the observer still runs (I have a break point inside the block).

Where am I going wrong at when removing the observer?

```
var postRefHandle: DatabaseHandle!
var query = DatabaseQuery()
var postsRefObserver = Database.database().reference().child("posts")

// called in viewWillAppear
func listen() {

    self.query = postsRefObserver
            .queryOrderedByKey()
            .queryLimited(toLast: 1)

    self.postRefHandle = self.query.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        // do something
    }
}

// called in viewWillDisappear
func remove() {

    if let postRefHandle = postRefHandle {
        self.postsRefObserver.removeObserver(withHandle: postRefHandle)
    }

    self.postsRefObserver.removeAllObservers()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the observer on the exact query object that you registered it on.

So:

```
self.query.removeObserver(withHandle: postRefHandle)
```

or

```
self.query.removeAllObservers()
```

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that `self.postsRefObserver.removeAllObservers()` shouldn't have worked btw given [these docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-removeallobservers). But the behavior has been like this for many years, that I doubt it can be changed at this point without unintended breaks.

Comment: I used the the first example that you gave with removing the handle and it worked perfectly. That’s good enough for me 